# como alterar a largura do JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Tags: joptionpane

Gostaria de saber como aumentar a largura da caixa de entrada do inputDialog?
Estou utilizando o codigo abaixo para abrir a caixa de dialogo para editar uma informação chamada "título", está funcionando, porém o titulo pode ser um pouco extenso e por isso gostaria que a caixa de dialogo fosse mais larga.

String resposta = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Edição de título:", "Editar Título",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,null,"Título");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIManager` é uma classe utilitária da biblioteca do Swing, na qual permite você alterar as propriedades dos elementos, definindo valores através de chaves e valores (assim como uma HashMap, por exemplo).

Para alterar o tamanho mínimo de um OptionPane, você pode alterar a propriedade `OptionPane.minimumSize`, ficando dessa maneira:

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize", new Dimension(500, 50));

String resposta = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Edição de título:", "Editar Título",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,null,"Título");
```

Você pode consultar a documentação sobre a classe UIManager [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html), e as propriedades [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/synth/doc-files/componentProperties.html).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Só que altera para os outros JOptionpane também, mais aí é só redefinir o tamanho para normal. Obrigado pela informação, essa me pareceu mais prática e eficiente das soluções que encontrei.